# VBA class module: private member of own class type withevents

Tags: vba, class

I want to create a sender -> receiver logic via a custom worksheet class so that changes of the sending worksheet table are given to the receiving custom worksheet object via an event.

Each custom worksheet object can have list objects with data.

I started with creating own class modules for every type of worksheet and connect them via "private withevents me_sendingSheetObjectType", but as all separate custom worksheet classes share practically all functionality, this would be overkill and copy-pasting code is not good.

So I tried to create a generic class which represents a custom worksheet object that can have a private member of the same custom worksheet object type to handle events.

But the debug-compile function gives me the error:

> Events cannot be processed for the given object.

on the line with the "WithEvents" deklaration of the private member.

Has anyone a clue how to fix this?

Code (class module **clsSheet**):

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents me_sendingSheet As clsSheet 'Debug-compile error here

Event tableChanged(data, lr As ListRow)

Public Function constructor(oSheet As clsSheet)
  
  Set me_sendingSheet = oSheet
  
End Function

'Desired Event Handler - not possible because of error

Private Sub me_sendingSheet_tableChanged(data, lr As ListRow)
 ' Some code here
End Sub
```

Comment: You simple cannot declare `WithEventsw` something else than an object **having events**. How that `clsSheet` object does look?

Comment: The code shown is that of clsSheet. As you can see, it has the event "tableChanged". The error is different from that one your comment implies. If you want to use "WithEvents" on a member that does not have events, the error is another one.

Comment: Do you mean that the code you show is of `clsShet` class? If so, it is even worst. I tried telling you before in which case you should use `WithEvents`. How do you imagine that an object not even being created can be referenced in a declaration of its own code? VBA is so confused than it was even able to imagine what you want doing, to raise a specific elocvent error messsage...

Comment: Why is that worse? I know the difference between class and object / instance. The above problem is apparently that the class cannot have a member of its own type withevents. Which is odd because *it has an event* as the code shows.

Comment: Declaring a variable As a class, makes the variable an object. It is not (only) a mater of "its own type"... It is exactly what I tried saying in my comments. **No object having events** exists in the moment you try declaring... It will work if another class to be instantiated supplies such an event...

Answer (score 0):

VBA WithEvents statement does not allow the type to be the same class as the class in which it is defined.

Instead, use a separate class as the source of events:

clsEventSource class module:

```
Public Event TableChanged(data, lr As ListRow)

Public Sub FireTableChanged(data As Variant, lr As ListRow)
    RaiseEvent TableChanged(data, lr)
End Sub
```

clsSheet class module:

```
'source of events from somewhere else that this instance wants to receive
Private WithEvents me_otherEventSource As clsEventSource

'sink for events this instance wants to publish
Private me_myEventSink As New clsEventSource

'hook up
Public Function ListenTo(eventSourceSheet As clsSheet)
    Set me_otherEventSource = eventSourceSheet.GetEventSource
End Function

'expose event sink (as a source to other instances)
Friend Function GetEventSource() As clsEventSource
    Set GetEventSource = me_myEventSink
End Function

'send data
Private Sub FireTableChanged(data As Variant, lr As ListRow)
    me_myEventSink.FireTableChanged data, lr
End Sub

'received data
Private Sub me_otherEventSource_TableChanged(data As Variant, lr As ListRow)
    MsgBox data
End Sub

'do something trigger for test
Public Sub DoSomething()
    FireTableChanged "I'm triggered", Nothing
End Sub
```

Test module:

```
Sub Foo()

    Dim sender As New clsSheet
    Dim receiver As New clsSheet

    receiver.ListenTo sender
    
    sender.DoSomething

End Sub
```